# SABnzbd port 8080 issues

Tags: server, docker

First of all, I'd like to start with "I have no idea what I'm doing". I've got a server at home which is set up by my brother and there are some issues. A reinstall seems like a great idea (and not too difficult for my brother), but since we live pretty far apart, plus the fact that we don't have much time off at the same time to do it remotely, I thought: let's ask here first before trying to schedule a reinstall session with my brother ;)

So, for the problem:

A while back my power was cut and all the sudden there were some problems on my server. The solution was to edit the host files (I'm not sure in what way, sorry, I can ask if this info is needed).

Yesterday, I've executed a `sudo upd -y` and got a timeout. After I rebooted, the update did work and I've rebooted again (and again) to see if everything worked as intended.

Basically everything works, Sonarr (port 8989) and Radarr (7878) are working fine, but SABnzbd (8080) isn't running.

The error before the host-file fix/change:
https://pastebin.com/KtfHUHyG

> sabnzbd    |   Unable to bind to port 8080 on localhost. Some other software uses the port or SABnzbd is already running.

Then, after the fix (and a reboot):
https://pastebin.com/K00KWK0M

> sabnzbd    | 2021-09-22 20:20:19,142::INFO::[_cplogging:213] [22/Sep/2021:20:20:19] ENGINE Bus STARTING
> sabnzbd    | 2021-09-22 20:20:19,149::INFO::[notifier:122] Sending notification: Error - [22/Sep/2021:20:20:19] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x7fd258012f10>>

So basically, I have no idea and thought, maybe someone here as a clue as how to fix this without reinstalling the whole server.

Thanks in advance and if I need to provide further details, please ask me to!

Kind regards,
Tjab

Edit 1:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Edit 2:

Using docker-compose to get the containers running.

Answer (score 0):

My brother found an ugly fix. A clone of the sabnzbd repo and an alteration on the service run file to run without ipv6. A better solution is to alter the docker-compose.yml but this results in multiple rights issues.